# Get EntityManager in normal Java Class

Tags: java, class, entitymanager

How can I get an entity manager in a normal java class? I tried it with Injection, but without any result, I always get a NullPointerException:

```
public class ClassName {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
    public EntityManager em;

    @Resource
    UserTransaction utx;

...
```

Then I tried it with a seperate class that provides the EntityManagerFactory, also without success, NullPointerException is thrown:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = null;
    static {
        try {
            entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPU");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }
}
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't just say "also without success". What was the problem with `createEntityManagerFactory()`? Exception?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: So `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPU");` did not throw any exception? Just returned `null`?

Comment: The container creates `EntityManagers`, and does injection. If you're not running in a container, there is nothing to create `EntityManager`s or do injection, so you need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class ClassName {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
    public EntityManager em;

    @Resource
    UserTransaction utx;
```

You have no Dependency.Injection here, if not running within a Java EE-Container.
These attributes are null. You need to initialize them first (Or add spring or another DI-container).

Comment: I see. I tried it as a HttpServlet which is running on JBoss. When it is called, it sets the EntitiyManager and the UserTransaction as planned. Thanks for the hint!